# Python: optimize.leastsq. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, scipy, syntax-error, least-squares, ambiguous

Everything work except for the last line. 
My goal is to calculate the best fit through the chi-squared test. There is something wrong with the application of leastsq function. 
z,d and d_err are arrays of the same length, given (the experimental data).

```
def df(z,omega_m,omega_l):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(omega_m*(1+z)**3+(1-omega_m-omega_l)*(1+z)**2+omega_l))

def DL(z,omega_m,omega_l,H_0):      #   checked with Hubble's law with low z, it is consistent
    f,err_f=scipy.integrate.quad(df,0,z,args=(omega_m,omega_l))     #   it's evident err_f it's irrelevant

    if omega_m+omega_l==1:
        return 299792./H_0*(1+z)*f

    elif omega_m+omega_l<1:
        fk=np.sin(np.sqrt(np.absolute(1-omega_l-omega_m))*f)
        return 299792./H_0*(1+z)/np.sqrt(np.absolute(1-omega_m-omega_l))*fk

    elif omega_m+omega_l>1:
        fk=np.sinh(np.sqrt(np.absolute(1-omega_l-omega_m))*f)
        return 299792./H_0*(1+z)/np.sqrt(np.absolute(1-omega_m-omega_l))*fk


params=(0.3,0.7,73) #   starting values for minimization   omega_m, omega_l, H_0

def chi(params,z,d,d_err):   #   checked, this function works
    return (d-DL(z,params[0],params[1],params[2]))**2/d_err

minimization,minimization_cov=optimize.leastsq(chi,params,args=(z,d,d_err))
```

This is the complete message of error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 360, in _quad
if (b != Inf and a != -Inf): ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What are `z`, `d` and `d_err` ? Can you send example data ? Else your code is hard to debug.

Comment: d is the array with the experimental data (compared with the model DL), d_err is the array of the d errors. z is the "sperimental indipendent variables" of d. omega_m, omega_l and H_0 are the parameters I need to find.

Comment: And shape and dtypes ? `z` is a float ?

Comment: They are all float arrays, sorry what do you mean with the "shape"? I expect similar values for the parameters with the initializing array "params" in the code.

Comment: do `print(z.shape, z.dtype)` and the same for the others.

Comment: (157,) float64
(157,) float64
(157,) float64

Comment: So `z` is not a scalar and @Mike Müller is right.

Comment: Notice all the SideBar questions?  You are using a boolean array in a context that expects a scalar, such as an `if`.  Here either `a` or `b` is an array, and it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `scipy.integrate.quad()` is the upper limit and must be a float. You use `z` as the third argument which is a NumPy array.

> Signature: scipy.integrate.quad(func, a, b, ...)
>
> Integrate func from `a` to `b` (possibly infinite interval) using a
>   technique from the Fortran library QUADPACK.

...

> a : float
>
> Lower limit of integration (use -numpy.inf for -infinity).
>
> b : float
>
> Upper limit of integration (use numpy.inf for +infinity).

Comment: How can I compute everytime only the z related to that step? I thought it was trivial it understood "z" as the z in that step.